# Find which points are vertices of polygon

Tags: math, geometry

I have points of polygon, some of the points are inside the polygon and some points are the vertices of this polygon. How can I know how many vertices this polygon has and which points are the vertices?

Comment: Without further constraints you can't know what you want to.  If you knew, say, that the polygon were convex you'd be able to get the *convex hull* of the set of points and figure out what you want from that.  But without some such additional information it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Convex Hull of the points. There are many viable algorithms for finding the hull; see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), for example.